# DI with beforeEach in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

I want to do the following:

```
describe('Questions', () => {
    var rest: RestService;
    var mockBackend: MockBackend;

    beforeEach((done) => {
        console.log('Executing before each');
        inject([RestService, XHRBackend], (_rest: RestService, _mockBackend: MockBackend) => {
            rest = _rest;
            mockBackend = _mockBackend;
            console.log('This never gets executed');
            done();
        });
    });

 ....
```

The callback inject is never called. Am I missing something, or must this be a more complex solution?

Comment: What Angular2 version?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be just

```
describe('Questions', () => {
    var rest: RestService;
    var mockBackend: MockBackend;

    beforeEach(inject([RestService, XHRBackend], (_rest: RestService, _mockBackend: MockBackend) => {
            rest = _rest;
            mockBackend = _mockBackend;
            console.log('This never gets executed');
    });
});
```

depending on your Angular2 version.

Comment: I did it that way to. Seems like a bug of sorts